# Prime elements in $\mathbb{Z}[[X]]$

Tags: commutative-algebra, power-series

I'm currently looking at prime elements in $\mathbb{Z}[[X]]$, so my question is whether $X$ or $1+X$ is prime in $\mathbb{Z}[[X]]$?

I personally believe that it is the case, because I can't think of any $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}[[X]]$ such that $X|ab$ but neither $X|a$ nor $X|b$ (or $1+X$ instead of $X$). But how do I show that? I thought I could compare this situation to showing that $X$ or $1+X$ is prime in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$. Back then, we basically used the fact that $\mathbb{Z}$ is a unique factorization domain and that $X$ and $1+X$ are irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}$. But how would one do that now?

Comment: $1+X$ is a unit.

Comment: $1+X$ is a unit in $\mathbf Z[[X]]$ , and its inverse is $1-X+X^2-X^3+\dots$.

Comment: If $X \mid ab$ with $a=\sum a_i X^i$ and similarly for $b$, then $a_0 b_0 = 0$ so either $a_0 = 0$ or $b_0 = 0$...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ring morphism  $\mathbb Z[[X]]\to \mathbb Z:\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_jX^j\to a_0$ has as kernel the ideal $\langle X\rangle $, hence that ideal is prime since $\mathbb Z[[X]]/\langle X\rangle \cong \mathbb Z$ is a domain.
But the ideal $\langle X\rangle$ being prime  is equivalent to the element  $X$ being prime so that , yes, $X$ is prime.